# UITabBar controller gives previous selected index?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I'm using Custom `UITabBarController` in the app to check selected index. I've this method to trigger when I select the `selectedIndex`:

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {

 //   print(self.selectedIndex)

    switch self.selectedIndex {
    case 1:

        print("should load feed " + String(self.selectedIndex))
        (self.viewControllers![1] as?  PageViewController)?.downloadNews()
   case 2:
        print("should load saved" + String(self.selectedIndex))
        (self.viewControllers![2] as? SavedController)?.loadData()
    default:
        return
    }
}
```

However I get old selected index when I click the new tab bar item. I know it's something easy any idea. Is there a way to takeout the right index in this method?

Comment: When you say the 'old selected index' what index do you get when you tap the first item and what index when you tap the second item?

Comment: I think you must call super before your operations. I guess that super change the value for selectedIndex.

Comment: No don't call the super version in this case because it will cause the app to crash.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually `selectedIndex` is not changed until `didSelect` happens.
Item index should be taken from the  the item itself.

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem)
{ 
   let indexOfTab = tabBar.items?.index(of: item)
   print("pressed tabBar: \(String(describing: indexOfTab))")
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The selectedIndex property of a UITabBarController is not updated until after the didSelect method is called.  In the didSelect you either do what is shown or use the UITabBarItem supplied directly.