# Present a View Controller modally from a tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I want to build a view with a camera. Something just like Instagram where there is a button in the middle that the user can click and the camera view shows up.
I implemented a code for the `TabViewController` in the `AppDelegate` but nothing happens, no animation or Presentation of the new `ViewController`.

Here is my AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit


class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: ViewController) -> Bool {
    if viewController is ViewController {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main.storyboard", bundle: nil)
        if let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "cameraVC") as? ViewController {
            controller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            tabBarController.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Here is my Storyboard:

[image: Main.storyboard]

Any ideas?

Comment: try calling this line: tabBarController.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil) from main queue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest to create a custom class for your TabBarController, then assign the delegate to that.

You can either assign and check the `restorationIdentifier` of the view controller, or do a type check. I usually use storyboard identifier as the restoration identifier of the view controller(s).

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.delegate = self
    }

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        if let identifier = viewController.restorationIdentifier, identifier == "cameraVC" {
            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "cameraVC") as! CameraViewController
            present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

Here's a sample you can play with: 
https://gist.github.com/emrekyv/3343aa40c24d7e54244dc09ba0cd95df

Comment: That helped! Thank You

Comment: Hey , I replaced the link with a gist.

Comment: @emrekyv the gist is 404

Comment: @emrekyv I think you need to remove the `edit` from the end of the link. I was able to access it after removing it. Also, thanks : it did help a lot.

Comment: goot catch, fixed!

Answer (score 2):

I just tried and It worked perfectly for me:

Create a Custom class for your TabBarController and assign it to your Controller in Storyboard.

After that override didSelect of tabBarController and write your presentation code there :

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
      
      if let controller = self.viewControllers?[self.selectedIndex] as? ViewController {

          controller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
          self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
       }
}
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: It helped me but `selectedIndex` is wrong in `didSelect`, see this answer to fix it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48193348/918602

Comment: I think you should put ")" end of second open bracket